# How use Switch to Change "text" in Python KIVY

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, kivy, kivy-language

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager , Screen

class StartWindow(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MyGrid(Widget):
    pass
kv = Builder.load_file('My.kv')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

**MY.kv**

```
WindowManager:
    StartWindow:

<StartWindow>:

    name: "start"
    BoxLayout:
      Label:
                text: 'Orign Word' if Language.active else 'Some tranlate'
                font_size: 30
            Switch:
                id:Message
                active: True
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
After run it i recive eror
What does it mean /////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
      20:        Label:
 --   21:            text: 'Welcome Vocabulary' if Language.active else 'Слава Україні'
 BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\Professional\Desktop\KivyProject\My.kv", line 21:
      20:        Label:
 --   21:            text: 'Welcome Vocabulary' if Language.active else 'Слава Україні'
      22:            font_size: 40
```

Comment: Can you give more details ? I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: What does *Language* refer to in `.kv` file ? Please add sufficient details.

Comment: The error message does not match the code you have provided.

Comment: @JohnAnderson , sorry my fail
'Welcome Vacabulary' = 'Orign wird'
'Some translate' = 'Слава Україні'